# Fade-in / fade-out with constant background color across animation

Tags: android, android-animation, alpha

I'm doing a fade-in/fade-out animation between two activities in Android. Both activities have a white background (Holo light theme). I change `alpha` from 0 to 1 in the activity that fades in, and from 1 to 0 in the activity that fades out.

My problem is that *the perceived background color is not constant across the animation*, which I find annoying. That is, the background darkens and then lightens over the duration of the animation. So in the middle of the animation the background will not be white, but rather a middle gray.

I'd like to use two interpolators such that the combined effect of both gives a constant background color. I thought that `linear` interpolators would do the trick, since they keep the sum of the two alphas constant. But it doesn't work: the background color changes during the animation. The standard `accelerate` and `decelerate` don't have the behaviour I want, either.

So, my question is: are there any known interpolators (perhaps `accelerate`, `decelerate` with certain rates) that give a constant background color in a fade-in / fade-out animation?

Comment: What you are describing is simply how the animation works. What it sounds like you want is just to animate one, then show the other after the animation is complete. You may need to write a custom animation (in `XML`) to get this right.

Comment: If I animete just one (a fade-out) the background color will unavoidably go from white (alpha 1) to black (alpha 0). Not what I want.

Comment: So if I understand right - you want a constant background color. So why are you animating anything? It seems like you should just show an overlay with the color you want for the time interval you want.

Comment: I am animating because there are more things in those activities, not just background. I want the views of those two activities to "melt" from those of first activity to those of second activity; but with constant background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

Short answer: *eliminate one of the two animations*. When going from main to secondary activity, use only a fade-in. When going from secondary to main activity, use only a fade-out. Details and explanation follow.

There are several ways to combine two colors with alpha values. The process is called "[alpha compositing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing)". One naive way of doing the combination, which is *not* the one commonly used, is:

> (a) C = C1*alpha1 + C2*alpha2

If that combination method were applied, using two linear interpolators for `alpha1` and `alpha2` would give a constant color wherever both `C1` and `C2` are equal to a "background" color `Cbg`. Specifically, if `alpha1 = t` (where `t` represents time), `alpha2 = 1-t` and `C1 = C2 = Cbg`, the  combination (a) gives `C = Cbg*t + Cbg*(1-t) = Cbg`. That is, the composite color `C` equals `Cbg` irrespective of `t`, as desired.

However, it appears that the combination which Android is applying is the so-called "over" operator:

> (b) C = C1*alpha1 + C2*alpha2*(1-alpha1)

where it is considered that the pixel with color `C1` is *over* that with `C2`. With the combination method (b), in order to get a constant color `C` for pixels with `C1 = C2 = Cbg` it is sufficient that `alpha2 = 1`, because then `C = Cbg*alpha1 + Cbg*1*(1-alpha1) = Cbg`.

So the interpolator should be *any* (linear or otherwise) for the activity which is *over* and `1` (no animation) for the activity that is *under*.

Since I wasn't sure how Android decides which activity is over and which is under, I did some experimentation and found that:

- When the main activity creates the secondary activity, the adequate procedure is to use a fade-in interpolator for the secondary activity.
- When the secondary activity goes back to the main activity, the adequate procedure is to set a fade-out interpolator for the secondary activity.

So it looks like Android is considering that *the secondary activity is over the main one*. This makes sense, since the secondary was created by the main one.

- Since the main activity doesn't have to use any animation, according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29) it should be sufficient to set its animation to `0`, that is, use `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, 0)`. However, I have found that this only works sometimes. To get it working, I need to define a "fake" fade which goes from alpha 1.0 to alpha 1.0 (so that it actually does nothing) and use `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fakefade)`.

As for the need of a fake animation instead of a `0` animation, I don't have an explanation.

I wish the Android documentation was clearer on this. It would have saved me quite some time.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it sounds like you want to animate the views in the activities, rather than the Activities themselves. You can do this using the [droidQuery](http://bit.ly/droidQuery) library. Simply set this as your `onPause()` method:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    //here, substitute mainView with the id of your background
    $.with(this, R.id.mainView).selectChildren().selectAll().animate("{ alpha : 0.0f }", 400, $.Easing.LINEAR, $.noop());
    super.onPause();
}
```

This will select all of the views that are children of your background, and animate their alpha values to 0 using `ObjectAnimator`, Linear interpolation, and 400ms duration.

You will also want to override `onResume()`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    //here, substitute mainView with the id of your background
    $.with(this, R.id.mainView).selectChildren().selectAll().animate("{ alpha : 1.0f }", 400, $.Easing.LINEAR, $.noop());
    super.onResume();
}
```

This does the opposite - animating from 0 alpha to 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With this approach, will the fade-in and fade-out in the two activities be simultaneous?

Comment: @LuisMendo I am not sure exactly, since these are view animations, and not activity transition animations, however coupled with an activity animation (`overridePendingTransition`), this should provide an effect pretty close to what you want.

Comment: I got it. Please see my own answer if interested. The desired effect is achieved by using _one_ alpha animation, not two.